# How to make text appear in next line when it overflows the parent div using css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want the "remaining books count" and "remaining pens count text" move to next line (below the numbers) when the number is more than two digits in other words when it overflows its parent div.

Below is my code,

```
function Text() {
    return (
        <wrapper marginTop={marginTop}>
            <View>
                <span>100</span>
                <span>/100</span>
            </View>
           <Text>
               remaining <br />
               <SubText>books count</SubText>
           </Text>
           <Divider />
           <View> 
               <span>100</span>
               <span>/100</span>
           </View>
           <Text>remaining <br />
               <SubText>pens count</SubText>
           </Text>
       </Wrapper>
  );

  const Wrapper = styled.div<{ marginTop?: number }>`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: ${props => (props.marginTop || 0) + 'px'};
  `;

   const View = styled.div`
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       align-items: baseline;
       margin-top: 8px;
    `;

     const Text = styled.span`
         margin-left: 8px;
     `;

      const SubText = styled.span`
          white-space: nowrap;
      `;

      const Divider = styled.div`
          height: 37px;
          margin-left: 16px;
          margin-right: 16px;
          border-left: 1px solid grey;
      `;


function Parent() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <LeftWrapper>
                <ContentBox height={30}>
                    <Overview />
                </ContentBox>
                <ContentBox height={70}>
                    <Main /> //this is where the Text component is rendered
                </ContentBox>
            </LeftWrapper>
            <RightWrapper>
                <ContentBox height={100}>
                    //some components rendered                           
                </ContentBox>
            </RightWrapper> 
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

function Main () {
    return (
        <>
            <Text/>
        </>
    )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 90vh;
    max-width: 90vw;
    flex: 1;
`;

const LeftWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 336px;
`;

 const RightWrapper = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100%;
     width: 864px;
 `;

  const ContentBox = styled.div<{ height: number }>`
      padding: 12px;
      width: calc(100% - 16px);
      height: calc(${props => props.height}% - 16px);
      margin: ${16 / 2}px;
 `;
```

when the digit is less than 3 in other words not overflowing within View of the Text component, then I want the text "remaining books count" and "remaining pens count" to be rendered like below

[image]

when the digit is more than 2 or in other words overflowing parent div, then I want the text "remaining books count" and "remaining pens count" to move to next line like below

[image]

How can I do this preferably using CSS? or a javascript solution is also okay. Could someone help me with this? thanks.

**EDIT:**

Text component is reusable. I want the text "remaining books count" "remaining pens count" to span to next line only when used within the Main component and nowhere else...

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

```
<Wrapper marginTop={marginTop}>
 <Section>
   <View>
     <span>100</span>
     <span>/100</span>
   </View>
   <Text>
     remaining <br />
     <SubText>books count</SubText>
   </Text>
 </Section>

 <Divider />

 <Section>
   <View>
     <span>100</span>
     <span>/100</span>
   </View>
   <Text>
     remaining <br />
     <SubText>pens count</SubText>
   </Text>
 </Section>
</Wrapper>;

const Section = styled.div`
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
```

Comment: this Text component is  a reusable component and i dont want the text to wrap to new line in some other component where this Text is used. however, tried adding your solution and the text wraps to new line. but the text "remaining " would be new line with a break then in next line "books count" is placed.

Comment: I want the whole text "remaining books count " to be in new line

Answer (score -1):

Would this solve your problem? Just add `wrapper--two-lines` class when 3 digits

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper--two-lines {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper--two-lines .left-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-wrapper">10/10</div>
  <div class="right-wrapper">remaining books count</div>
 </div>

<div class="wrapper wrapper--two-lines">
  <div class="left-wrapper">100/100</div>
  <div class="right-wrapper">remaining books count</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks but this value 100/100 is dynamic it can also be 0, 10, 100 , 1000 or anything

Comment: well the idea is the same. Make your react component add the class when you want to display elements in different lines. For example.

const className = `${value}`.length > 2 ? "wrapper wrapper--two-lines" : "wrapper";

Comment: based on your answer i have added flex-wrap to place where Text component is used within the Main component wrapped Text with div with class wrapper-two-lines. this pushes the remaining books count text to next line with remaining break and books count in next line again.